# How to get async function return in nodejs when the data is returned via method function (jest test)

Tags: node.js, async-await, jestjs

I have an application and I am trying to write jest test for function in it.

Function looks like:

```
function standup(userId, client, triggerId) {
//some calcs
  db_query(key, user_id)
    .then(db_result => {
   return client.views.open({ //data })
})
})
```

`client.views.open` is framework funtion which does some stuff.

In test I thought I can just create method open in client object:

```
client = {
  views: {
    open(obj){
      return obj
    }
  }};
```

And get data with test like:

```
test('test', () => {
  return standup(userId, client, triggerId).then(data => {
    expect(data).toBe(//data);
  });
});
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I am getting *undefined*. I went through different answers and some documentation, but I still do not understand how this async stuff is made to work. I could use callback functions for tests, but then my application will not work.

Could you explain how it should be done correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adjusting prod function:

```
function standup(userId, client, triggerId) {
  //some calcs
  db_query(key, user_id)
    .then(db_result => {
      return client.views.open({ //data })
    })
});
```

Looks like the problem was in "mix" of approaches and .then in original function was causing issue.

Like this:

```
function standup(userId, client, triggerId) {
  //some calcs
  const db_result = await db_query(key, user_id)
  return client.views.open({//data})
}
```

And test like:

```
it('Slashcommand /standup test', async () => {
 const value = await standup(userId, client, triggerId);
 expect(value).toMatchObject({//data})
})
```

It works as expected as in prod as in tests.

Answer (score -1):

Try passing the done callback to your test. This lets jest know when your test has finished processing

```js
test('test', (done) => {
  return standup(userId, client, triggerId).then(data => {
    expect(data).toBe(//data);
    done();
  });
});
```

Alternative, you can use the async/await syntax

```js
test('test', async (done) => {
  const await data = standup(userId, client, triggerId);
  expect(data).toBe(//data);
});
```

Jest Docs for reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Comment: Still getting: undefined as function result

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker I've just noticed, your standup function is never returning anything

Comment: It does. 
If set like:
client = {
  views: {
    open(obj){
      console.log(obj)
      return obj
    }
  }};
It returns data in console.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker Looks like you've all fixed it now anyway. Glad it's resolved